# std::bind doesn't work with reference?

Tags: c++, reference, compilation, bind

I've got following program and it works:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<functional>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::placeholders;
void f(int i,int j){
    ++i;
    ++j;
}
int main(){
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    bind(&f,_1,i)(3);
    bind(&f,j,_1)(4);
    return 0;
}
```

But if I change f to receive reference, and add ref() to bind:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<functional>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::placeholders;
void f(int &i,int &j){
    ++i;
    ++j;
}
int main(){
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    bind(&f,_1,ref(i))(3);
    bind(&f,ref(j),_1)(4);
    return 0;
}
```

Well it fails to compile:

clang --std=c++11 gives following error:

```
no matching function for call to object of type '__bind<void (*)(int &,
  int &), std::__1::placeholders::__ph<1> &, int &>'
bind(&f,_1,i)();
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Use lambda instead of bind. Use at least -std=c++14!

Comment: `f(i,4)` is also an error.

Comment: std::ref doesn't create a reference, it creates a reference_wrapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bind(&f, _1, ref(i))(3);
bind(&f, ref(j), _1)(4);
```

Generally speaking, it is the same thing as calling:

```
f(3, i);
f(j, 4);
```

Where function `f` is defined as:

```
void f(int &i, int &j) {
    ++i;
    ++j;
}
```

But you cannot bind *non-const lvalue reference* (like `int &i`) to *rvalue* (like `3`), that is why the compiler complains.